# Our YouTube Data API Keys are getting error "accessNotConfigured"

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, http-status-code-403

We are working with YouTube Data APIs for more than 5 years now and we have an enterprise offering which is been used from 90% of all Media and Entertainment organizations in the US. That includes YouTube Originals btw.

For the past 2 weeks our API Keys are blocked and returning 403 errors:

```
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured. YouTube Data API has not been used..."
```

We successfully go over an App Review last July at which point we also got a Quota increase. For the past 2 weeks, I am submitting forms to increase the quota (since it is set to Zero with no apparent reason) and emailing support and basically zero response from YouTube. At this point, our business is at risk since we cannot fulfill data requests by Customers and there is no communication from YouTube.

We even provided them with App Access and logins (since as I mentioned above YouTube besides a data provider is also a customer) and we do see humans from YouTube login our app and playing around but no meaningful response yet.

We also created new keys but with a limit of 10000 calls a day its impossible to collect all necessary data mainly because our customers have videos with 10s of thousands of comments.

Any suggestions or anybody from YouTube monitoring this?